# Dynamic module import in Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ecmascript-6

I have a bunch of modules defined in an Ember CLI app and each starts with the same path. I would like to import the modules into a module in the app. For example, I could write:

```
import post1 from 'posts/1';
import post2 from 'posts/2';
import post3 from 'posts/3';

export default Em.ObjectController.extend({
  posts: Em.A(post1, post2, post3),
});
```

However, I do not know the module names because they are created/named on the fly by a precompiler. All I know is that the path always begins with the same string. In this case, `posts`.

Is there a way to import all modules that begin with a particular path? For example, how can I do *something* like the following:

```
import posts from 'posts/*';

// or

registry['posts'].forEach(postId, i) {
  var path = 'posts/' + postId;

  import i from path;
}
```

Each of the modules I want to find and import has exported an object.

I have been through the [ES6 module transpiler](https://github.com/esnext/es6-module-transpiler) docs but can't find much.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by `precompiler`?? ember-cli precompiler???

Comment: 'Precompiler' meaning a template precompiler written as an ember addon that's manipulating the tree and adding javascript objects as ES6 modules for certain file extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ES6 spec doesn't allow you to dynamically import modules using the `import` keyword. All importing and exporting using the module syntax must be done statically. However, it does provide a programmatic API that you can use to dynamically import modules. [This article](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#the_ecmascript_6_module_loader_api) has a great summary of it (as well as a great summary of the rest of ES6 modules).

My suggestion would be to wrap Ember's loader API in a ES6 compliant wrapper. For instance, Ember-CLI uses the `require()` function to get modules, so you could do something like this:

```
window.System = window.System || {};
window.System['import'] = function(moduleName) {
    return Ember.RSVP.Promise.resolve(window.require(moduleName));
}

// ...

System.import('my-app/posts/' + postNumber).then(function(postModule) {
    // ...
});
```

You could also use the Ember `require()` function directly, my way just protects you in the likely event that Ember changes their module loader.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is there anyway to know what the available modules for importing are? In your example I don't know what the possible options for `postNumber` are.

Comment: I've answered my own question: `for (var module in window.require.entries) { }`.