# How does lazy module loading work in ES6

Tags: javascript, import, module, lazy-loading, ecmascript-6

How can I *lazily-load* ES6 modules? By *lazy*, I mean I don't want to actually load modules that **aren't needed**. For example, here's something I can do with RequireJS:

```js
function someEventHandler() {
    var SomeModule = require('some-module'),
        module = new SomeModule();
    // ...
}
```

Something along the same lines doesn't appear to be possible using ES6 imports:

```js
// Doesn't appear to be valid...
function someEventHandler() {
    import SomeModule from 'some-module';
    var module = new SomeModule();
    // ...
}
```

Are there any viable techniques to only pull in dependencies when needed, using ES6 modules? Or is the only path to trace the full dependency graph and fetch everything up-front?

Comment: You have to use the system loader API. See [Dynamic module import in Ember CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26728035/218196)

Comment: No, it is not possible using `import` syntax. You can however use an asynchronous(!) equivalent of the `require` function.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `import` statement will only work in the very top of files, and it will load all of them. This is mainly to avoid potential issues with circular dependencies.

There will also be a way to do asynchronous loading; however the specification doesn't seem to be finalized yet. The [ES6 module loader](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader) polyfill package uses a method called `System.import(moduleName)` that returns a promise and the final specification is likely to look similar:

```
function someEventHandler() {
    System.import('some-module').then((SomeModule) => {
        var module = new SomeModule();
        // ...
    })
}
```

Comment: There is now a proposal for dynamic import from JavaScript: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import. It specifies a simple `import()` function on the global scope. WebPack 2 supports this sinve version v2.1.0-beta.28.

Comment: Example for lazyloading jQuery in ES6 :

import('jquery').then((jquery) => {
            // Because jquery is the module, here is the new syntax for using this 
            window.$ = jquery.default;
            window.$('#id');
});

Answer (score 6):

Example for lazyloading jQuery in ES6 :

```
import('jquery').then((jquery) => {
     // Because jquery is the module, here is the new syntax for using this 
          window.$ = jquery.default;
          window.$('#id');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This *dynamic import* functionality is now available as part of the ECMAScript specification - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import